# how to have an easily transferable LaTeX environment?

Tags: packages, external-files

I've installed a number of `sty` TeX packages in my machine (under `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/`). I also have a number of LaTeX documents (`tex`  files) in a github repository which I would like to be able to compile on any  machine in which I may clone that repository.

The problem is that every time I am using a different machine and try to compile the LaTeX documents (e.g. using `pdflatex`) I get a large number of errors because, obviously, the packages I rely on (using `\usepackage`) are not available in the new machine and so I have to spend some time recreating my LaTeX enviornment in that new machine. I.e. copying the same `sty` files in the new machine's `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex` directory.

What would be an appropriate approach to ensure that my LaTeX environment is easily transferable between machines? E.g. perhaps maintain the contents of my `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex` directory in a github repository?

Comment: If they are standard packages from ctan then normally you don't need to install them by hand in such a directory, just let texlive or miktex package manager install them in the systems main texmf tree.

Comment: Yes, I tend to do full installations of TeXLive in all machines, there is no point being selective. Also MikTeX can automatically download needed packages. Are you talking about really special sty files, if they are really special they can be in the source directory.